# Login box in a page using Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm trying to show a login box in my page only if the user is not authenticated yet.
I'm using Spring Security 3.0.

Do I have to check inside the view (JSP page) through some value I set on the model while processing the request in the Controller or is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking inside the JSP seems the most straightforward here. The Spring Security taglib lets you do just that.

See http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html

Comment: Remember to add to the project the library referenced by the document above (in my case it was spring-security-taglibs-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar )